# Export data to pdf file without using ITextSharp in Asp.Net

Tags: pdf

Hi I am looking on how to export data(in table format) to a PDF file. But I cannot use ITextSharp Due to licensing issues with it. Can anybody suggest any MIT license tool for it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [PDFsharp & MigraDoc](http://www.pdfsharp.net/).

They are published under the MIT License.

Comment: I saw this tool earlier. Specifically i want to export a grid view data to a PDF file. Can you help me out with it?

Comment: Ok but still does not support emojis.  :(  XtextFormatter & Ximage useful for me.